# IF statement breaks class compilation with "Non-void method" error

Tags: apex

I'm getting a `Non-void method might not return a value or might have statement after a return statement`error on the following method:

```
    public String getImage() {
        List<Document> documents = [SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE Name like 'myImage%' LIMIT 1];
        if(documents.size() > 0) { <----- Compile fails here
            backgroundImage = documents[0].Id;
            return backgroundImage;                      
        }       
    }
```

If I remove the `if` statement, it works fine, but obviously, I need one.

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error and how to rectify it?

Comment: I changed the title so that it was more obvious when looking at it in a list exactly what the question was.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you declare that your method is going to return a String as such:

```
public String getImage() {
```

The compiler is going to check that a String variable, in some form or other, will always be returned.

Your `if` block puts the only return statement in a block of code that *sometimes may not return something*. And given that sometimes it might not return something, it means that it is sometimes invalid code. And until we crack quantum computing for the masses, "sometimes" doesn't work...so the compiler, of course just considers it to be invalid.

Validity is all-or-nothing.

You simply need to provide some mechanism to return a String. In this case, probably in an `else`, or always return a String, but have it to be something else if statement is not true.

```
    public String getImage() {
      String backgroundImage;
      List<Document> documents = [SELECT Id FROM Document WHERE Name like 'myImage%' LIMIT 1];
      if(documents.size() > 0) { <----- Compile fails here
        backgroundImage = documents[0].Id;                      
      }  
    return backgroundImage;      
}
```

This ensures that there is always some return value...even if `null`.

Comment: Actually you get the green tick for the much more informative answer! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

add this

```
else {
  return null;
}
```

You need to return something since you have specified it.

Comment: You get the green tick when the 8min mandatory timer expires.